# How to use Molecule inside a VM to test an Ansible role that installs Docker

Tags: docker, ansible, virtualbox, molecule

I have an Ansible role that among other things installs Docker and starts the docker daemon in a CentOS environment. I would like to use Molecule to test it, but as my workstation is a Windows PC I have to run Molecule from a VirtualBox VM. At least theoretically my options are:

- Use Molecule's Vagrant driver and run a VM inside my VM
- Use Molecule's Docker driver and have a docker container which starts the docker daemon.

As far as I can tell the first option is not really possible with VirtualBox; is there a way to achieve the second one? I searched around, but all the posts I found concerned running Molecule itself from within a container rather than the setup I described.

If I try to use a default Molecule scenario systemctl fails to start the docker daemon.

Comment: `delegated` driver and another VirtualBox VM side-by-side with the one with Molecule?

Comment: I'll have to check this out.